# How do I optimize this SQL query comparing a value in two possible columns?

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

I've written a SQL query that uses six tables to construct the output for a separate C# program, and I'm looking for a way to speed up the search.

I walked through the execution plan and I notice that one spot in particular is taking up 85% of the execution time, labeled with a comment in the code block below with `--This spot right here`.

```
select distinct 
    ta.account_num as 'Account', 
    tl.billing_year as 'Year', 
    tl.billing_month as 'Month', 
    ta.bill_date as 'Bill Date', 
    DATEDIFF(DD, cast(cast(tl.billing_year as varchar(4)) + right('0' + cast(tl.billing_month as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + (case when billing_month in (4,6,9,11) and bill_date > 30 then '30' when billing_month = 2 and bill_date > 28 then '28' else cast(bill_date as varchar(2)) end), 2) as datetime), GETDATE()) as 'Past', 
    DATEADD(Day,10,d) as 'To be Loaded Before',
    p.provider_name as 'Provider', 
    c.client as 'Client',
    tip.invoice_load_type as 'Load Type'
from 
    tm_invoice_load tl
inner join 
    tm_client c on tl.client_id = c.client_id
inner join 
    tm_client_account ta on (ta.account_num = tl.account_num or ta.pilot = tl.account_num) --This spot right here
inner join 
    provider p on p.id_provider = ta.id_provider
inner join 
    tm_calendar cal on DATEPART(DAY, d) = DATEPART(DAY, entry_dt)
                    and DATEPART(MONTH, d) = DATEPART(MONTH, entry_dt)
                    and DATEPART(YEAR, d) = DATEPART(YEAR, entry_dt)
inner join 
    tm_invoice_load_type tip on tip.invoice_load_type_id = ta.invoice_load_type_id
where
    not exists (select top 1 id 
                from tm_invoice_load 
                where billing_year = tl.billing_year 
                  and billing_month = tl.billing_month 
                  and status_id = 1 
                  and (account_num = ta.account_num or account_num = ta.pilot))
    and ta.status_id = 1
    --and ta.invoice_load_type_id = 2
    and tl.status_id = 2
    and (ta.pilot is null or ta.account_num <> ta.pilot)
order by 
    c.client, p.provider_name, ta.account_num, tl.billing_year, tl.billing_month
```

Above, it's when joining `tm_client_account`, where it has an account number column, and a pilot in case it is a child to another account.  When such a thing happens, the parent account is NOT selected (`ta.pilot is null or ta.account_num <> ta.pilot`), and instead the child accounts are shown.

The query works exactly as intended, but it's kinda slow, and as these tables grow (and they are doing so on a nearly exponential curve) it will only get worse.

Is there some way that I can accomplish this join in a faster way?  Even small gains would be great!

If it helps, I'm running this on SQL Server 2008 R2.

[Here is a screenshot](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v366/PhantomOfTime/ExpdExecPlanCombined_zpsmf6nuqwv.jpg) of the execution plan.  If needed, I can provide more/different information.

Comment: For perfomance question you have to include [QUERY PLAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Is there a particular way to best present it here?  Based on the post you linked to, there are more than a few, and I wonder which is preferred here, as I have not previously asked any such questions...

Comment: Regarding the query-plan, ideally you run the query in SqlSentry Plan Explorer (free is fine), then do File/Save as.. and save it as a .queryanalyis file. Zip and share it somewhere. If that's not an option you can do the same in SSMS; right click the Query Plan and choose save as.... Works too but retains less info. Anyway, from the screenshot it seems there is one particular JOIN that eats 85% of the cost, check the pop-up to get more info when you hoover over it.

Comment: @deroby I actually put a comment in the code block indicating which `join` is causing the problem (`tm_client_account ta on (ta.account_num = tl.account_num or ta.pilot = tl.account_num)`)... I got that far, but I wasn't sure how to change it in a way that would be more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything really wrong with the query. I tend to keep 
things like `ta.status_id = 1` inside the relevant (ta) `JOIN` clause rather than in the `WHERE`, but the query optimizer is smart enough to handle that.

The one thing that I'd suggest to change is this one:

```
inner join 
tm_calendar cal on DATEPART(DAY, d) = DATEPART(DAY, entry_dt)
                and DATEPART(MONTH, d) = DATEPART(MONTH, entry_dt)
                and DATEPART(YEAR, d) = DATEPART(YEAR, entry_dt)
```

Try to replace it with this and see what happens:

```
inner join 
tm_calendar cal on Convert(date, d) = Convert(date, entry_dt)
```

The result should be identical but this way the system can still use the index (and statistics) on the `d` and/or `entry_dt` fields. `Convert(date,...)` is one of the few SARG-able converts there are.

Apart from that it all depends on the indexes available, the amount and distribution of the data.

---

UPDATE: as you mention that the heavy cost (85%) seems to come from the `ta` part, here some thoughts

I've taken the liberty of reformatting the query a bit so it makes more sense to me. Mainly I've grouped the relevant parts together so it's more clear (to me) what's being done on what table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       ta.account_num as 'Account', 
       tl.billing_year as 'Year', 
       tl.billing_month as 'Month', 
       ta.bill_date as 'Bill Date', 
       DATEDIFF(DD, cast(cast(tl.billing_year as varchar(4)) + right('0' + cast(tl.billing_month as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + (case when billing_month in (4,6,9,11) and bill_date > 30 then '30' when billing_month = 2 and bill_date > 28 then '28' else cast(bill_date as varchar(2)) end), 2) as datetime), GETDATE()) as 'Past', 
       DATEADD(Day,10,d) as 'To be Loaded Before',
       p.provider_name as 'Provider', 
       c.client as 'Client',
       tip.invoice_load_type as 'Load Type'
  FROM tm_invoice_load tl

  JOIN tm_client c 
    ON tl.client_id = c.client_id

  JOIN tm_client_account ta 
    ON (ta.account_num = tl.account_num or ta.pilot = tl.account_num) --This spot right here
   AND ta.status_id = 1
   AND (ta.pilot IS NULL OR ta.account_num <> ta.pilot)
 --AND ta.invoice_load_type_id = 2

  JOIN provider p 
    ON p.id_provider = ta.id_provider

  JOIN tm_invoice_load_type tip 
    ON tip.invoice_load_type_id = ta.invoice_load_type_id

  JOIN tm_calendar cal 
    ON Convert(date, cal.d) = Convert(date, tl.entry_dt)

 WHERE tl.status_id = 2
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM tm_invoice_load xx
                    WHERE xx.billing_year = tl.billing_year 
                      AND xx.billing_month = tl.billing_month 
                      AND xx.status_id = 1 
                      AND (xx.account_num = ta.account_num OR xx.account_num = ta.pilot))

  ORDER BY c.client, p.provider_name, ta.account_num, tl.billing_year, tl.billing_month
```

Could you give the query as it is here a try and time it + check the query plan?

Focussing on `tm_client_account` the next logical step would be to add a specific index on this table for this query.
The problem is that the filtered index capabilities of MSSQL are ... well, challenging =)

The closest I get is this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON tm_client_account (account_num) INCLUDE (pilot, bill_date, id_provider, invoice_load_type_id) WHERE (status = 1)
```

Could you create the index and see if that helps?
If the query-plan shows that rather continues using a table-scan on `tm_client_account` then add `WITH (INDEX = idx_test)` to the `JOIN` clause and try again.

If all that doesn't really cut down on the time the query takes you could try pre-filtering things by means of an indexed view. 
WARNING: Keep in mind though that adding indexes to the table will cause some performance degradation when doing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on the table; adding a filtered view on it will double-so! If the data in this table (very) volatile, the indexes and/or view might make other parts of your system noticably slower. Then again, SQL is pretty good at this so the only way to know for sure is by testing.

Step 1: create the view

```
CREATE VIEW v_test_tm_client_account_filtered
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT id_client_account, -- I am assuming that there is an identity-field like this on the table, adapt as needed!
       account_num, 
       pilot,
       bill_date, 
       id_provider,
       invoice_load_type_id
  FROM tm_client_account ta
 WHERE status = 1
   AND ta.status_id = 1
   AND (ta.pilot IS NULL OR ta.account_num <> ta.pilot)
 --AND ta.invoice_load_type_id = 2
```

Step 2: index the view

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_test ON v_test_tm_client_account_filtered (account_num, pilot, id_client_account)
```

Step 3: adapt the query to use the view rather than the table directly

```
  JOIN tm_client_account ta 
    ON (ta.account_num = tl.account_num or ta.pilot = tl.account_num) --This spot right here
   AND ta.status_id = 1
   AND (ta.pilot IS NULL OR ta.account_num <> ta.pilot)
 --AND ta.invoice_load_type_id = 2
```

becomes

```
  JOIN v_test_tm_client_account_filtered ta 
    ON ta.account_num = tl.account_num 
    OR ta.pilot       = tl.account_num
```

And then run the query once more...

Comment: After finally having enough time to test all proposed adjustments, I was very surprised to find that the original query was still faster than anything here (in fairness, I suspect total server load was the largest factor, bigger than anything in these queries).  The difference was often less than 200ms over a 7 second span.  Strangely, the reorganizing you did for readability - which should have had no impact - added almost a consistent second to the query time.  I used 4 versions of this query for testing to compare options, and when there was a difference, the original was still the fastest.

Comment: In fairness, the first index (on tm_client_account) was in place for all testing, but I noticed that by itself it did very little (a consistent gain of less than 200ms).

Comment: RDBMSs can be very much alike black magic sometimes =) If you really need to squeze down those 7 seconds I'd suggest to give QueryPlan Explorer a go and see if it shows anything worth tweaking further. Another option might be to JOIN only some tables first, dump the result in a temp-table, maybe index said temp-table and then JOIN all the rest. 
Judging which tables to 'pre-JOIN' is off course tricky. This largely depends on how well you know the data at hand and how well you can estimate how things will inter-connect. And whether this will also be the case for other load data. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this with a similar issue, the only way I've been able to make this any faster has been to tell the query not to lock the data.  I don't know why this helped, but it cut the query time in less than half.  This has had no effect on the returned data, and explicitly sorting it makes it unapparent.

```
select distinct 
    ta.account_num as 'Account', 
    tl.billing_year as 'Year', 
    tl.billing_month as 'Month', 
    ta.bill_date as 'Bill Date', 
    DATEDIFF(DD, cast(cast(tl.billing_year as varchar(4)) + right('0' + cast(tl.billing_month as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + (case when billing_month in (4,6,9,11) and bill_date > 30 then '30' when billing_month = 2 and bill_date > 28 then '28' else cast(bill_date as varchar(2)) end), 2) as datetime), GETDATE()) as 'Past', 
    DATEADD(Day,10,d) as 'To be Loaded Before',
    p.provider_name as 'Provider', 
    c.client as 'Client',
    tip.invoice_load_type as 'Load Type'
from 
    tm_invoice_load tl

with (nolock) --This accelerates the select statement!

inner join 
    tm_client c on tl.client_id = c.client_id
[...]
```

Meanwhile a computed column was added, and this query is still down from 7-8 seconds to 2.5-3.5 seconds.  Again, I don't know why, but it helped.  It might help someone else too.